# Starting Apache with a different config file fails without any error message

Tags: apache

For testing purposes I want to run an Apache locally (ultimately as a non root user) and keep the Apache config files in my central repository. According to the Apache documentation ( http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/configuring.html ) I can set the config file with the `-f` switch and the ServerRoot with the `-d` switch ( http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/httpd.html ).

Now my problem is that when I try to start Apache with

```
sudo apache2 -d $(pwd)/testApacheRootDir/ -f $(pwd)/testApacheRootDir/testingApacheConf -k start
```

the process exits without actually starting Apache (and without any) error messages.

I know the config file is read, as the above command will print error messages if there is an error in the file. Apache also actually uses the ServerRoot dir, as an (empty) `error_log` file is created under `$(pwd)/testApacheRootDir/logs/`.

My Apache config file looks like this:

```
Listen 80

NameVirtualHost localhost:80

<VirtualHost localhost:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/cms
ServerName cms.testing
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost localhost:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/vendor
ServerName vendor.testing
</VirtualHost>
```

and `apache2 -V` prints:

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Nov  6 2012 20:27:25
Server's Module Magic Number: 20051115:30
Server loaded:  APR 1.4.6, APR-Util 1.4.1
Compiled using: APR 1.4.6, APR-Util 1.4.1
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     Worker
  threaded:     yes (fixed thread count)
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APACHE_MPM_DIR="server/mpm/worker"
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=128
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/apache2"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/lib/apache2/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/var/run/apache2.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="apache2.conf"
```

Do you have any advice what might be wrong?

Comment: Have you looked at /var/log/apache2/*? Anywhere else in /var/log/*?

Comment: @Perleone: Yes, I have. There is nothing there. Thank you anyway.

Comment: I actually know the answer now (a User and Group directive was needed, thanks goes to @larsks), but I cannot answer my own question for another 6 hours as new user :(

Comment: have you tried the "apachectl graceful" command? this one just worked for me. I had syntax errors in my httpd.conf

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why the error message is never written to the log files or the console output, but what was missing was a User directive. After adding

```
User    www-data
Group   www-data
```

everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Occasionally Apache will encounter errors after parsing the configuration file but before logging has been initialized.  In this case, the error messages are printed to `stderr`, but starting Apache as you are doing hides any output from the process.  Try running it like this:

```
apache2 -X -d $(pwd)/testApacheRootDir/ -f $(pwd)/testApacheRootDir/testingApacheConf
```

The `-X` flag causes Apache to run in the foreground:

> -X     Run httpd in debug mode. Only one worker will be started and the server will not detach from the console.

This should allow you to see any error messages printed to `stderr`.

If that doesn't work, here's a big hammer:

Run Apache under the control of `strace`, and then examine the trace file to see if you can spot a problem.  Start Apache like this:

```
strace -o trace -f -s 1024 apache2 -X -d $(pwd)/testApacheRootDir/ -f $(pwd)/testApacheRootDir/testingApacheConf
```

This will write a system call trace to the file named `trace`.  Examine this file (starting from the bottom, probably) for any `write` system calls that contain error messages, or for errors in system calls (e.g., `ENOENT` because a directory specified in your config is missing or mistyped or something).

The `-f` flag asks `strace` to follow forks, and `-s 1024` means that it will record up to 1024 characters in calls to `write`, etc.

Comment: The -X flag looks very useful, thank you. Unfortunately there is still no output (and I immediately return to the prompt).

Comment: The last line in `trace` is `27267 write(2, "[Thu Jan 10 17:31:22 2013] [alert] getpwuid: couldn't determine user name from uid 4294967295, you probably need to modify the User directive\n", 142) = 142`. I don't know where it should have been written, but that helps me a lot. Thank you :)